# AddStackExchangeRedisCache - multiple connections created

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redis, .net-5, stackexchange.redis

I have a Web API in .NET 5 that uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`. I have added the `IDistributedCache` implementation of Redis cache using an extension method from the given package.

```cs
services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(options =>
{
    options.Configuration = Configuration.GetConnectionString("RedisConnection");
});
```

Now, when I request something from Redis (and since it's a singleton), it should create 1 connection due to the inner implementation ([Github link](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/release/5.0/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs)) of IDistributedCache performing `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect()` once. However, when I use `redis-cli` and perform the `client list` command, it lists me 3 total connections (1 of me currently connected via `redis-cli` and the other two from the API. Should that be happening at all since it's, well, 1 connection really?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=6 addr=127.0.0.1:4396 fd=9 name= age=3305 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
127.0.0.1:6379> client list
id=6 addr=127.0.0.1:4396 fd=9 name= age=3317 idle=0 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=32768 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=client
id=11 addr=127.0.0.1:1046 fd=12 name=PC age=4 idle=3 flags=N db=0 sub=0 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=hmget
id=12 addr=127.0.0.1:1048 fd=11 name=PC age=4 idle=4 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the second SE.Redis connection, it's a subscriber:

```
id=12 addr=127.0.0.1:1048 fd=11 name=PC age=4 idle=4 flags=N db=0 sub=1 psub=0 multi=-1 qbuf=0 qbuf-free=0 obl=0 oll=0 omem=0 events=r cmd=subscribe
```

Under the hood, SE.Redis is setting itself up to listen to events published through redis, in particular, I think it's setting itself up to hear from other SE.Redis instances that the master has changed. In theory, if there is a failover, one of the SE.Redis instances will detect it and will publish to the channel `__Booksleeve_MasterChanged`, which will signal to the other instances to failover. There's only 1 connection that you will send things over but the subscriber connection will be used for that other stuff. You can run `redis-cli monitor` to see the subscriptions coming through from SE.Redis.